# npm run build error, no such file or directory, open 'build/bundle.css'

Tags: css, node.js, wordpress, unix, system-administration

I'm attempting a routine-test of a customized WordPress-installation on a localhost production supported by the [node package-manager](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm). After instantiating the WordPress core-files, ensuring successful connection to the database and updating a few assets, I attempted to change-directory into the corresponding WordPress-theme files to run the node-package-manager install command with `npm install` (which was successful) and then attempted to execute the CSS-compiler with `npm run build`as per routine; however, on this attempt, I encountered the following errors within my below terminal output:

```
vetsi npm run build

> @ build /Users/alexsingleton/Sites/vetsi/wp-content/themes/vetsi
> npm-run-all --silent compile:css compile:js

/Users/alexsingleton/Sites/vetsi/wp-content/themes/vetsi/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:715
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'build/bundle.css'
    at Error (native)
ERROR: compile:css: None-Zero Exit(1);

npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/alexsingleton/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.4/bin/node" "/Users/alexsingleton/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.4/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ build: `npm-run-all --silent compile:css compile:js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script 'npm-run-all --silent compile:css compile:js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm-run-all --silent compile:css compile:js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/alexsingleton/.npm/_logs/2017-02-15T17_48_20_907Z-debug.log
➜  vetsi
```

I've tried updating both the node package manager with `npm install -g npm`  and verified the correct version corresponding to another successful localhost production with `nvm ls` generating the below output:

```
vetsi nvm ls
        v0.12.7
->       v4.4.4
         system
default -> 4.4.4 (-> v4.4.4)
node -> stable (-> v4.4.4) (default)
stable -> 4.4 (-> v4.4.4) (default)
iojs -> iojs- (-> N/A) (default)
➜  vetsi
```

Needless to say, the above-errors preclude any localhost pages from rendering, though I can successfully access and navigate within the WordPress Content Management system.  I would appreciate any guidance- thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the localhost-production within the console of Google Chrome Inspector Tools, the error reported that the entire [node package-manager folder and dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) were missing.  Since neither `npm-install` nor `npm build` didn't instantiate the package-folder or dependencies, I simply copied the files from my other working localhost production, specifically **bundle.css** where it was apparently missing from the appropriate path (**wp/themes/vetsi/build**).  For now, this hack is the best solution to my problem but I welcome alternative analysis or clarification as to why the aforementioned commands didn't correctly execute according to my previous successes.  Thanks!